# Enable IIS Application with 2.0 framework to work through TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, iis, tls1.2

Would like to know ways to enable an application targeted to 3.5 framework and deployed with 2.0 framwork in IIS to work with protocol TLS 1.2.

Searched that there was ways of adding code as below to source code to get through the protocol. But it is not working and says the security protocol is not supported.

```
public const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
public const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
```

or

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question can mean two things.

If the question is, we have an application hosted on an IIS server (Windows 2008 or higher) and we want all clients to be able to use TLS1.2 to connect to this web server.

Then the answer is, you’ll have to enable it on server level. There’re some settings in the registry, but you can also use the small [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) application. (You’ll have to restart the server after changing these settings).

If your application connects to some other web application, and should use TLs1.2 you’re in trouble. This is only supported starting from .Net 3.5.1 with a hot fix.